# How to rename more than one files in ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, files, rename

I have so many images more than 100 in a folder such as:

```
apple.jpg
grapes.jpg
orange.jpg
....
```

I want to rename all of them at once with ascending order numbers such as:

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
....
```

How can I do it using Ubuntu 10.04? Is there any terminal command to do it.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure how you want them numbered, but the following Perl script should do it (haven't tested it out, but should probably work):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
@a=glob("*.jpg");
$n=1;
for(@a){
    rename $_,($n++).".jpg";
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try the following in terminal:

```bsh
 find . -name '*.jpg'| awk 'BEGIN{ i=0 } { printf "mv %s %d.jpg\n", $0, i++ }'| bash
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure bash solution (bash version of [o_o's perl script](https://askubuntu.com/a/217509/112879)):

```
n=1; for f in ./*.jpg; do mv "$f" $n.jpg; n=$((n+1)); done
```